# Set Default font family and font size in sap ui5 rich text editor

Tags: fonts, sapui5, default

I was able to get the richtext editor working for in sap ui5 by the following code

```
    sap.ui.require(["sap/ui/richtexteditor/RichTextEditor", "sap/ui/richtexteditor/EditorType"],
                    function (RTE, EditorType) {
                var oRichTextEditor = new RTE("myRTE", {
                    editorType: EditorType.TinyMCE4,
                    width: "100%",
                    height: "200px",
                    customToolbar: true,
                    showGroupFont: true,
                    showGroupLink: true,
                    showGroupInsert: true,
                    value: sHtmlValue,
                    ready: function () {
                        this.addButtonGroup("styleselect").addButtonGroup("table");
                    }
                });

                that.getView().byId("textarea").addContent(oRichTextEditor);
            });
```

Now the client wishes to have the default font family and font size to `Arial` and Size `11` be default.

Can you help me how I am able to set these defaults?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box RTE does not support 11 pt. You have to enhance the available list of valid font sizes.

Then in the `beforeEditorInit` event you can apply your settings

```js
sap.ui.require([
    "sap/ui/richtexteditor/RichTextEditor",
    "sap/ui/richtexteditor/EditorType",
    "sap/ui/richtexteditor/library"
], (RTE, EditorType, RTELibrary) => {
    // RTE only supports a few FontSizes out of the box. Add your additional FontSize here
    const aFontSizes = RTELibrary.EditorCommands.FontSize;
    aFontSizes.push(11);
    aFontSizes.sort((a, b) => a - b);

    const oRichTextEditor = new RTE("myRTE", {
        editorType: EditorType.TinyMCE4,
        customToolbar: true,
        showGroupFont: true,
        beforeEditorInit: function (oEvent) {
            const oConfig = oEvent.getParameter("configuration");
            const fnSuperSetup = oConfig.setup;
            oConfig.setup = (oEditor) => {
                // if you want you can call the original setup method here
                fnSuperSetup(oEditor);
                oEditor.on("init", function () {
                    oEditor.execCommand("FontName", false, "arial, helvetica, sans-serif");
                    oEditor.execCommand("FontSize", false, "11pt");
                });
            };
        }
    });

    this.getView().byId("mainPage").addContent(oRichTextEditor);
});
```

Small drawback: The dropdown doesn't select the correct value (11 pt). But you can see in the source code that it is really 11 pt:

[image]

Maybe someone else has an idea why the dropdown doesn't update correctly when calling `execCommand` (it only works for elements smaller than the one inserted).

Comment: I have a ready function which is overwriting the settings for the font in beforeEditorInit. ready: function () {
                        this.addButtonGroup("styleselect").addButtonGroup("table");
                    }. I need a table in the options.

Comment: Is there a way to add the table button in the beforeEditorInit function, so I will get rid of the ready function